# Deleting single value from Pinia reactive data store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia, vueuse

I am creating a multistep register form in which I provide an avatar upload. Because it is a multistep form, I want to store the data in a Pinia store until the form finally gets submitted. Everything works fine so far. But I want to be able to delete the value that contains the Blob URL for the avatar, so the user can choose a different image. What I am trying to do is this `userRegisterStore.cardOwner.avatar = ''` cause the initial state of that value is just an empty string. But I get this error message:

`runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:218 Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'avatar'`

I also use cropperjs and vue-cropperjs. But I think that's irrelevant in this case.
I Googled all day and found nothing. So, I hope someone here can help.

[EDIT]
I created a [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/michaelgrossklos/temp_card_owner/fix-image-delete) I hope it works. The first file you should see is RegisterFormFive.vue. To view it, you need to go to this link or use the integrated preview in codesandbox: https://n9dfv3-5173.preview.csb.app/register. Then upload an image, crop it (orange button beneath the image), and then try to delete it (red button)

Here's my code:

```
// RegisterDataStore.js

export const useRegisterDataStore = defineStore('RegisterDataStore', {
  state: () => ({
    imgReady: false,
    cardOwner: reactive({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      agbAccepted: false,
      dsgvoAccepted: false,
      title: '',
      companyName: '',
      companyPublic: false,
      position: '',
      positionPublic: false,
      avatar: '',
      addresses: [],
      contacts: [],
      links: [],
    }),
  }),
```

```
// Cropper part

<Cropper
      v-if="registerDataStore.cardOwner.avatar && !registerDataStore.imgReady"
      class="mx-auto max-h-[350px] max-w-[350px] overflow-hidden rounded-lg border-2 border-skin-primary bg-skin-primary"
      ref="cropper"
      alt="User avatar"
      drag-mode="move"
      :src="registerDataStore.cardOwner.avatar"
      :aspect-ratio="1 / 1"
      :crop-box-movable="false"
      :crop-box-resizable="false"
      :auto-crop-area="0.6"
      :guides="false"
      :movable="true"
      :scalable="true"
      :zoomable="true"
      :zoo-on-touch="true"
      :max-canvas-width="350"
      :max-canvas-height="350"
      :zoom-on-wheel="true"
      :rotate-on-drag="false"
      :rotatable="false"
      :background="false"
      :modal="true"
      :initial-aspect-ration="1 / 1"
      :view-mode="1"
    ></Cropper>
```

```
// Conponent script

<script setup>
  import HeaderNav from '@/components/HeaderNav.vue'
  import HeaderTitle from '@/components/HeaderTitle.vue'
  import { useRegisterDataStore } from '@/stores/RegisterDataStore'
  import Cropper from 'vue-cropperjs'
  import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css'
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import { useObjectUrl } from '@vueuse/core'

  name: 'RegisterFormFive'

  const registerDataStore = useRegisterDataStore()
  const avatarInput = ref(null)
  const cropper = ref(null)

  const fileChanged = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0] || e.dataTrtansfer.files[0]
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      registerDataStore.cardOwner.avatar = e.target.result
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }

  const deleteAvatar = (event) => {
    registerDataStore.cardOwner.avatar = null
    registerDataStore.imgReady = false
  }
</script>
```

```
// The button that tiggers the storage

<div class="mt-4 flex justify-center">
      <button
        v-if="!registerDataStore.imgReady"
        @click.prevent="
          cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob((blob) => {
            registerDataStore.cardOwner.avatar = useObjectUrl(blob)
            registerDataStore.imgReady = true
          })
        "
        type="button"
        class="hover:bg-skin-primary-dark inline-flex items-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-skin-primary px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-skin-primary focus:ring-offset-2"
      >
```

```
// The file input field

    <input
      type="file"
      ref="avatarInput"
      accept=".jpg,.png"
      @change="fileChanged"
      :style="{ display: 'none' }"
    />
```

```
// The button that should "delete" the value

 <button
        v-if="registerDataStore.imgReady"
        @click.prevent="deleteAvatar"
        type="button"
        class="hover:bg-skin-primary-dark inline-flex items-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-red-700 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-skin-primary focus:ring-offset-2"
      >
        <IconWarning
          class="mr-2 h-5 w-5 fill-current text-skin-primary"
          aria-hidden="true"
        />
        Bild löschen
      </button>
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to mutate a state outside a store. You shouldn't use `reactive` in `state`. I don't think it affects the way it works but any way, it's just not needed there. Otherwise I see no explanation for this error. Please, provide a way to reproduce it. Consider moving the code from `@click.prevent` to a script, this will make debugging easier. It's unknown at which point the error happens.

Comment: @EstusFlask First of all, thanks for the tipps. I created a [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/michaelgrossklos/temp_card_owner/fix-image-delete) I hope it works. The first file you should see is RegisterFormFive.vue. To view it, you need to go to this link or use the integrated preview in codesandbox: https://n9dfv3-5173.preview.csb.app/register . then upload an image, crop it (orange button beneath the image), and then try to delete it (red button)

Comment: The sandbox is not available for editing. Did you try to remove reactive like suggested above?

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, I tried to remove it before I posted the question here. Didn't work either. You can fork the repo if you want: https://github.com/michaelgrossklos/temp_card_owner

Comment: @EstusFlask "It's a bad practice to mutate a state outside a store": how exactly is it "bad"? I think from what I remember, this is one of the biggest reasons Pinia was created while Vuex exists. In Vuex, it was "bad" only because time travelling wasn't possible if you did that which ultimately makes debugging harder. This in my opinion only comes down to preference.

Comment: @m4heshd The same concerns apply to Pinia, it's seen as the next Vuex version. It's hard to debug things when they are implicitly changed anywhere in the app. Vuex has a check for a state mutated outside mutations, while Pinia doesn't. Time traveling is currently not supported in Pinia devtools

Comment: @EstusFlask I agree that it doesn't do the "time-travel" per se. But check the devtools timeline. The mutations are easily trackable. That's pretty much time-travel without the "travelling" part of it. So I don't see any issue with direct mutations. We do it all the time on absolutely massive applications and never ever had a problem with debugging or the usage itself. "In pinia you don’t create an action to just change the state. You can use $patch to directly change the state." - Original developer of Pinia. The direct mutation fear is merely a bandwagon misconception coming from Vuex days.

Comment: @EstusFlask Also here's a tweet, the man himself approving direct mutation. https://twitter.com/jswriter_/status/1559996454072209410

Comment: @m4heshd Yes, you *can*, as long as you're fully aware of the consequences. YMMV, I can clearly see how this can cause problems with debugging on the large scale from my experience with other global stores. It's a tad easier with Pinia because $subscribe already exists (that's what devtools do) and gives a usable call stack (not necessarily so for other stores) but still more complex than just tracking action calls. It's basically declarative vs imperative at this point, not specific to stores.

Comment: @EstusFlask I do know that it's using `$subscribe` under the hood. Pretty obvious and out there. What I'm trying to say here is there's no "consequence" to doing this either way. There are no "problems with debugging". I don't know what you're referring to there. I deal with massive Vue apps on a daily basis and nobody has ever experienced a problem with this approach. The only "consequence" of this is a developer thinking there are consequences because somebody else said so. That's all I'm saying here. There's absolutely no drawback and it's proven again and again even by the Vue dev team.

Comment: There's a consequence, I can tell this from my experience. The common and obvious debugging case is "we ended up with data in a store that shouldn't have been there". It's as easy as putting a breakpoint inside an action, and this can even be done in prod with no sourcemap and no Vue devtools. It's not about being dogmatic, it's about ditching established good practices for no reason and writing potentially inferior code. There's no opinion of Vue team there, the link about is a personal opinion of a single team member. Any way, if it works for you, then good for you.

Comment: The only thing I took away from that is "established good practices" which clearly means "things I'm used to doing, for a long time". That's what I realized while arguing about this. Just like yourself, Me and my team are used to direct mutation and never ever had a problem with debugging of functionality. As you said, this clearly comes down to personal preference. What I wanted to establish was it's not a good idea to ENFORCE your preference when neither is a "bad practice". A dev should be comfortable to practice whatever method as long as they don't break any functionality or make problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested `reactive` isn't needed in `state`, Pinia state is already reactive. `@click.prevent` handler doesn't need to be created in a template, it doesn't affect how it works but makes debugging harder.

VueUse `useObjectUrl` composable is the problem. Due to how Vue reactive API works, refs are unwrapped inside reactive object. Since `useObjectUrl` returns readonly ref, it makes `cardOwner.avatar` property readonly and prevents from reassigning a value. Changing it would require the whole object to be reassigned:

```
registerDataStore.cardOwner = { ...registerDataStore.cardOwner, avatar: ... }
```

The actual problem is that `useObjectUrl` is misused. Since `blob` value doesn't change in the scope of `then` function, it can't benefit from being reactive. The composable should be replaced with the actual thing that it does:

```
registerDataStore.cardOwner.avatar = URL.createObjectURL(newObject)
```

Comment: I thought about that. The problem could be VueUse. I tried `URL.createObjectURL()` in the first place but that didn't work. That's why I used VueUse then. I will check it out. Thanks.